# Android Studio: Context Menu Icons don't appear

Tags: android

I have a list view and a context menu on items of the list.
I try to create an extremely simple thing - add icon to context menu using android:icon.
Context menu appears, but no icon shown.
What did I wrong?
Thank you.

My context menu xml and mainactivity.java are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:title="Delete" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="Add" />
</menu>


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ListView listView;
    String listItems[]={"One", "Two", "Three"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select the action");

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always try to get a local copy as the icons from your SDK folder as these resources are bound to change, and app behavior might not be same.

Note:

> If you want to use any icons or other internal drawable resources, you should store a local copy of those icons or drawables in your application resources, then reference the local copy from your application code. In that way, you can maintain control over the appearance of your icons, even if the system's copy changes.

After you get a local copies for both try this:

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/action_delete"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
   android:showAsAction="always"
   android:title="Delete" />

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Add" />
```

There are various resources also which are not public through SDK, so best practice is to have a local copy.

Comment: I copied icons as a loclal copy and tried to use showAsAction, but without an result. No icons shown on floating context menu.